# Google map not showing in tab fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using a Tab layout in my project. One of the tab fragments should show World map. My app is integrated with Google map API and I used ViewPager for setting the adapter.  Below is the activity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), HomeActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Cloud", "Home", "Report" };
    Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, HomeActivity context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MapFragment();
            case 1:
                return new OneFragment();
            case 2:
                return new TwoFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        return tab;
    }

}

    }
```

And my fragment is

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment  {

private MapView mMapView;

private GoogleMap mMap;

View view;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Lat : " + latLng.latitude + " , "
                                    + "Long : " + latLng.longitude,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
             });

            if (mMap == null) {
                mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                mMapView.onCreate(getArguments());
                mMapView.onResume();

                try {
                    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
                    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gmap) {
                            mMap = gmap;
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                            //fill markers
                            //add marker listener

                        }
                    });



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

         }

    });
    return view;
}

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory(){
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }


}
```

my application running successfully. and in the first tab the fragment can be loaded and am able to see the latitude and longitude values also when clicking on the screen. but not able to see the google map. Shared below the image. the same code is working perfectly in separate activity. Please help to find what I have missed to add. 
[screenshot](http://C:%5CUsers%5Cu31385%5CDesktop%5CScreenshot_20181004-133533.jpg)

Comment: add onTouch listener to view where you show continents, and depending on how you show them, determine whether the touch point is inside the shape of this or that continent

Comment: Any help please

Comment: That was help in my comment, wasn't it?

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko, I have edited the question in detail with complete code. I would like to know why I am not able to see the map in one of my tab's fragment.

Comment: you editted it the way it is totally different from original question. You can't get answers this way, as your question is already gone far from the first pages, and nobody will likely see it anymore. Restore the original question, and ask new ine instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by generating a new key for Google map API and updated it in manifest file. And now am able to see the google map in one of my tab fragments working perfectly along with other fragments.